# Add posts select checkboxes using Advanced custom fields

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have two custom post types called hotels and rooms. Users can register to my web site and they can add their hotels and rooms from their wp backend. so my problem is when they are adding hotels they need to select their hotel rooms.

I'm using Advanced custom fields and it has field type called post object. but that field displaying posts in select menu. I need to do it with checkboxes.So it'll be so easy to user.

I really appritiate if someone can help me.

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever accomplish this? I've been wondering how to do the same as I don't find the current selection method very intuitive to novice users.

Comment: yes. but not with ACF. I used the Option Framework.  https://wordpress.org/plugins/options-framework/

Answer (score 1):

It will require a little bt of code along with ACF

Add checkbox field (ex : brands) and add following code in your functions.php file

```
function my_acf_load_field( $field )
{
    global $post;
    $field['choices'] = array();
    wp_reset_query();
    $query = new WP_Query(array('show_posts' => 100));
    foreach($query->posts as $product_id=>$macthed_product){
            $choices[$macthed_product->ID] = $macthed_product->post_title;
    }
    $field['choices'] = array();

    if( is_array($choices) )
    {
        foreach( $choices as $key=>$choice )
        {
            $field['choices'][$key] = $choice;
        }
    }
     wp_reset_query();
    return $field;
}
add_filter('acf/load_field/name=brands', 'my_acf_load_field');
```

use [wp query parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to filter posts.

Post id will be the checkbox value with title as label in metabox.

Comment: This answer worked for me, but I had to use the following in my WP_query:
WP_Query(array('posts_per_page' => 100, 'post_type' => 'location', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'order' => 'ASC'))

Comment: Also, you should comment out or delete the wp_reset_query(); lines. They can cause problems if you try to access your checkbox field from within another loop.